# Al utilizar función sha1 de php, se obtienen valores diferentes para el mismo dato

Tags: sha1

Un saludo cordial.

Estoy probando la función sha1 para calcular el hash de un string (clave), para realizar un simple login de usuarios registrados; capturo la clave en la BD a través de un FORM y lo almaceno en una variable una vez calculado el hash sha1, de esta forma para el registro de usuario :

```
     $clave = strip_tags(sha1($_POST['clave']));

<?php if($existe = mysqli_fetch_object($query))
      {  echo "<script language = javascript> swal({title: 'Error!', text: 'El usuario *".$usuario."* ya existe!'})</script>"; } 
      else
      { $meter = mysqli_query($conexion, 'INSERT INTO usuarios (clave) values 
        ("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $clave).'", "'.$ip.'")');  
   ?>
```

al realizar este registro calculando el hash sha1 para la clave:  "mas" obtengo en BD el siguiente valor: "5f8992a5f5df2e39cfde"

ahora muestro como ingreso la misma clave en login para compararlo con el hash sha1 registrado anteriormente en la BD. no antes de hacer hash sha1 tanbien para este "mas" que se ingresara en el login como clave, esta clave "mas" para el login, tanbien lo capturo a través de un Form.

muestro Login:

```
$clave = strip_tags(sha1($_POST['clave']));
    
$consulta= "SELECT id_usuarios,usuario,clave,cargo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='".$usuario."' AND clave='".$clave."'";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
$fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

pero al realizar este ultimo hash sha1, en el login con la misma clave "mas" ingresada en el registro de usuarios, para intentar compararlos y lograr acceder, se obtiene un diferente valor al optenido en la BD al hacer hash sha1 en el registro de usuarios.

el valor obtenido en login es:

"5f8992a5f5df2e39cfdeb44c93f510059a99dc51" ---> hash de login.

es decir si comparamos con el hash del registro de usuarios, veremos que este ultimo optenido es mas largo:

"5f8992a5f5df2e39cfde" -----hash de registro de usuarios.

que estamos haciendo mal en login para optener un hash diferente ? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Te recomiendo que no uses sha1, en la misma documentacion dice que no se recomienda. En su lugar usa password_hash(): https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash y para verficiar la contraseña usa password_verify(): https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify

Comment: Es probable que el campo donde almacenas el hash en tu tabla tenga una limitación en el número de caracteres y eso hace que se almacene un hash truncado. Verifica eso en la tabla, y cambia el uso de `sha1` por un algoritmo más robusto. Saludos

Comment: Mateo Guio,, Considero tu respuesta, al momento solo estoy haciendo pruebas, investigare sobre password_hash(), gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Mauricio Contreras; agradezco tu intervención y efectivamente me falto espacio para mas caracteres en la BD, eso era el inconveniente. gracias por tu aporte, me enseño algo importante....

Comment: @Mas no olvides responder a tu propia pregunta, y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.